# Facebook incorrectly declining Action Tagging

Tags: action, facebook-opengraph, tagging

Not sure if the is the best place to be posting this but not sure where else I could.

My app is basically a form which they fill in to get on the guestlist for an event, so they select the event (object) and add their details and the number of guests that will be with them. On submission this creates an action i.e Joe Blog is on the guestlist for an event.

As the guests that are coming with them might be their friends on Facebook it makes sense to be able to tag those friends so that they know they are on the guestlist too.

However Facebook is declining this and saying...

> The action tagging property you submitted doesn't meet our requirement of authentically tagging other users you've shared an experience with. For Open Graph actions the action tagging additional property can only be used when both users are performing the action.

I far as I can tell my app meets these requires as the people tagged will be sharing the experience i.e Joe Bloggs is on the guestlist for an event with Friend 1 and Friend 2

Hopefully someone from Facebook will see this and properly explain why it's getting declined as I don't see why (in their examples) you can cook a recipe with someone but not be on a guestlist with them.

Answer (score 1):

> On submission this creates an action i.e Joe Blog is on the guestlist for an event.
>
> As the guests that are coming with them might be their friends on Facebook it makes sense to be able to tag those friends so that they know they are on the guestlist too.

Nope.

Action tagging is supposed to tag friends that are at the *physical* location of an action and are *undertaking* this action together.

“Being on a guestlist” does not have a physical location, and is nothing you “undertake” either – it is just that, *being on a list* (so I would question whether it is a real “action” altogether, since it is not *active*, but rather *passive*).

[Quote from docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/tagging/#taggingpeople):

> *“For instance, you should use it to say, Austin is eating at The Ballpark with Rose. Not, Austin will eat at The Ballpark with Rose, since the action has not yet occurred with that person.”*

-

> I far as I can tell my app meets these requires as the people tagged will be sharing the experience i.e Joe Bloggs is on the guestlist for an event with Friend 1 and Friend 2

That you say “*will* be sharing the experience” here should be a clue all in itself – when Joe and his friends actually *attend* the event when it is happening, *that* might be worth of action tagging then.

For what you want, you should look at [mention tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/mention-tagging/) instead.

Comment: Being on the guestlist does have a physical location as the event is at a location, and the fact they are on the guestlist means they are attending that event and that place.

Maybe I should change my action to attending rather than guestlist to avoid any confusion.

Comment: No, being on a guestlist does not have a physical location, since a guestlist is just a piece of paper. Attending the actual event would be different – but here you still have the problem, that (besides you don’t know if anyone __will__ actually attend the event just because they are on the guestlist) you are trying to publish an action that has not happened yet (if you still try to publish it the moment you are putting them on the guestlist).